# A question about performance comparison between Snakemake and Nextflow

Tags: resources, pipeline, snakemake, nextflow

I want to compare two pipeline using same data while one is written by snakemake and the other is nextflow. But I met a problem when setting computation resource.

For nextflow, I can only set cpus and memory in config file. The threads number can not be set but automatically assigned.

In snakemake, I want to set the same computational resource as nextflow. But although I can set cpu by --cores and memory, I can't make the threads setting automatically (its default 1).

So I just wonder if simply setting cpus and memory of each is OK?

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The difference between runtimes of the frameworks should be negligible compared to the runtime of the analysis.

Comment: yeah, I want to compare the performance of two pipeline. One is written in snakemake and the other is nextflow. All of them aim to do the same thing but use different software. I want to do an experinment of which will be faster and better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your issue fully, but from what I take from it, you want to compare the overall performance of two workflows for the same kind of analysis. One is written in Nextflow and one in Snakemake.

I think it should be OK to simply give both workflows the same amount of overall resources globally, and let them figure out the resource usage of individual steps. In snakemake, this is done globally with the [`snakemake` command-line call via the options](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/executing/cli.html#execution):

- CPUs: `--cores 24`
- memory: `--resources mem_mb=64000`

For a fair comparison you should also ensure that these resources are actually (fully) available for the workflow runs. Especially make sure that there are no competing processes running on the server(s) you are running the workflows on.

For memory, note that for Snakemake (and maybe also for Nextflow?) it depends on how well a workflow and its rules are written, if the specified limit is actually respected by each step / process.